# How to make a plotly bar graph with the correct value count with python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

data looks like this

| A | label |
| --- | --- |
| string | negative |
| string | negative |
| string | negative |
| string | positive |
| string | positive |
| string | negative |
| string | positive |

I want to make a simple plotly bar chart showing two bars - the count of positive and the count of negative, next to each other, blue and red.

If I do this

```
fig = px.bar(df, x=df["label"])
```

then I get this (btw do you know why the colors are muted out of nowhere?):

[image]

When I hover it says "count = 1 " I want it to say the actual count.. and I want to make the negative bar red. How do I do that?

Comment: See [plotly color sequencing](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plotly** has histogram chart type.  https://plotly.com/python/histograms/

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""A,label
string,negative
string,negative
string,negative
string,positive
string,positive
string,negative
string,positive"""))

px.histogram(df, x="label", color="label", color_discrete_sequence=["red","blue"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do `groupby` and aggregate with `count` to get a new DataFrame with the count for the two classes under `label`:

```
fig = px.bar(df.groupby([‘a’]).count(),x=‘label’,color =‘label’, color_discrete_sequence=[‘blue’,’red’])
```